# regex expression to replace first occurrence of “#” with “ _”

Tags: c#, regex

How can I  build a regex expression to replace first  occurrence of `#` with `_`.

I  need to  change `f2b1_last_name_buyer` to  `f2b1#last_name_buyer`

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "^([^_]+)_", "#", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

but it scubs all of the characters to the first  _

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
var input = "f2b1_last_name_buyer";
var pattern = "_";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var result = regex.Replace(input, "#", 1);

//Do something with result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(subjectString, "^([^]+)", "#", RegexOptions.Singleline, 1);
```

Last parameter is number of replacements to make before stopping.

See the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx

Comment: How is this getting so many upvotes, while it is not even working?

Comment: You're right, sorry. The code-fragment is wrong, there is no overloaded Replace(String, String, String, int32) method. The example at the link will help though, or OakNinja's answer below.

Comment: Not only your code is wrong, the regex is also wrong. It encounters fatal error during run time.

Comment: I copied the regex from the original post without verifying it, as he said it was working, but was replacing all instances. I pointed the reader to documentation showing an example that he can adapt for own needs.